# Docker Multi-stage Builds and Test results - How to get them?

Tags: docker, testing, build-error, docker-multi-stage-build

Apparently, all articles I found about multi-stage builds cover the happy path.

But how to get the test results (e.g. unit or acceptance tests) out of a builder-container when something fails?

Answer (score 2):

I think that you can do things like

```
 docker build --target test -t <your_test_image> .
```

Then you could just run this image with volumes attached and gather results...

More [here](https://docs.docker.com/develop/develop-images/multistage-build/).